# Seeking Feedback on React Authentication System Implementation

Tags: react.js, typescript, authentication, rest, jwt

I've developed a React authentication system for my application and would like to receive feedback on its correctness and potential improvements. Below is an overview of the key components and functionalities of the system:

1. `App.tsx`: This file serves as the entry point for the application. It checks the user's authentication status and fetches user data accordingly. If the access token is missing or invalid, it triggers a logout procedure and clears all persisted states.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
    import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
    import '../public/favicon.ico';
    
    import { getUser } from '@services/user.service';
    import { loginSuccess } from '@redux/slices/auth.slice';
    import { persistor } from '@redux/store';
    import useAuth from '@hooks/useAuth';
    import { handleApiError } from '@utils/errorHandler';
    import { getAuthTokens } from '@utils/auth';
    import createRoutes from './routes';
    
    function App() {
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      // Check if the user is authenticated by checking availability of tokens
      const isAuthenticated = useAuth();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchUser();
      }, [isAuthenticated]);
    
      /**
       * Get user data or initiate logout procedure
       * @returns
       */
      const fetchUser = async () => {
        try {
          const authTokens = getAuthTokens();
    
          // check if access token is missing if so reset user data from redux state
          if (!authTokens?.accessToken) {
            // Dispatch the PURGE action to clear all persisted states
            persistor.purge();
            return;
          }
    
          const response = await getUser();
          if (response?.data) {
            // update redux state
            dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
          }
        } catch (error) {
          handleApiError(error);
        }
      };
    
      // Memoize the routes configuration to prevent unnecessary re-renders
      const routers = useMemo(() => createRoutes(isAuthenticated), [isAuthenticated]);
    
      return <RouterProvider key="router" router={routers} />;
    }
    
    export default App;
```

2. `useAuth.tsx`: This custom hook retrieves the authentication state from the Redux store and determines if the user is authenticated based on the presence of access tokens.

```
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { RootState } from '@redux/store';
    import { getAuthTokens } from '@utils/auth';
    
    const useAuth = () => {
      const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
    
      // Retrieve the authentication token
      let authTokens = null;
      try {
        authTokens = getAuthTokens();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error retrieving authentication token:', error);
      }
    
      // Determine if the user is authenticated
      const isAuthenticatedUser = !!(authTokens?.accessToken && isAuthenticated);
    
      // Return the authentication state
      return isAuthenticatedUser;
    };
    
    export default useAuth;
```

3. `utils/auth.tsx`: This module contains utility functions for managing authentication tokens securely using encryption. It includes functions for storing, retrieving, and removing authentication tokens from storage.

```
    import { ITokens } from '@interfaces/auth.interface';
    import { encryptStorage } from './storage';
    
    /**
     * Extracts the access token from a Bearer authorization header.
     * @param authorizationHeader The Bearer authorization header string.
     * @returns The access token extracted from the authorization header, or null if the header is missing or invalid.
     * @example
     * Example usage:
     * const authorizationHeader = 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI...';
     * const accessToken = getAccessTokenFromBearer(authorizationHeader); // output: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiI...
     */
    export const getAccessTokenFromBearer = (authorizationHeader: string): string | null => {
      if (!authorizationHeader) {
        return null; // Handle missing header case
      }
    
      const parts = authorizationHeader.split(' ');
      if (parts.length !== 2 || parts[0].toLowerCase() !== 'bearer') {
        console.error(`Invalid Authorization header value received`);
        return null; // Handle invalid format
      }
    
      return parts[1];
    };
    
    /**
     * Stores the authentication tokens securely using encryption.
     * @param {ITokens} tokens - The authentication tokens containing access token and refresh token.
     */
    export const storeAuthTokens = (tokens: ITokens) => {
      const { accessToken: bearerAccessToken, refreshToken } = tokens;
      // strip out `Bearer` part from thr token
      const accessToken = getAccessTokenFromBearer(bearerAccessToken);
    
      // Store the tokens securely using encryption
      encryptStorage.setMultipleItems([
        ['accessToken', accessToken],
        ['refreshToken', refreshToken],
      ]);
    };
    
    /**
     * Retrieves the authentication tokens securely using encryption.
     * @returns {ITokens | null} The authentication tokens containing access token and refresh token, or null if not found.
     */
    export const getAuthTokens = (): ITokens | null => {
      // Retrieve the tokens securely using encryption
      const accessToken = encryptStorage.getItem('accessToken');
      const refreshToken = encryptStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    
      // Return the tokens if both are present, otherwise return null
      if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
        return { accessToken, refreshToken };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
    
    /**
     * Removes the authentication tokens from storage.
     */
    export const removeAuthTokens = (): void => {
      // Remove the tokens from storage
      encryptStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
      encryptStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
    };
```

4. `user.service.tsx`: This service module handles API requests related to user data, including fetching user information from the server.

```
    import { USER } from '../api/apiEndPoints';
    import instance from '../api';
    import { ISignUpInput } from '../types/user.interface';
    
    export const createUser = (userData: ISignUpInput) => {
      return instance.post(USER.CREATE_USER, userData);
    };
    
    export const getUser = () => {
      const data = instance.get(USER.GET_USER);
      return data;
    };
```

5. `api/index.ts`: This file configures Axios interceptors for adding access and refresh tokens to request headers and handling authorization failures.

```
    import axios, { AxiosError, InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
    
    import { persistor } from '@redux/store';
    import { getAPIBaseURL } from '@configs/index';
    import { getAuthTokens, removeAuthTokens } from '@utils/auth';
    
    // doc: https://axios-http.com/docs/instance
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: getAPIBaseURL(),
      timeout: 30000, // 30 seconds
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    
    // Add a request interceptor to add access and refresh tokens to request headers
    instance.interceptors.request.use(
      async (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
        // Get authentication tokens
        const tokens = getAuthTokens();
    
        // Add access token to headers if available
        if (tokens?.accessToken) {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokens.accessToken}`;
        }
        // Add refresh token to headers if available
        if (tokens?.refreshToken) {
          config.headers['Refresh-Token'] = tokens.refreshToken;
        }
    
        return config;
      },
      (error: unknown) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );
    
    // Add a response interceptor to handle authorization failures
    instance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        // Return the response if successful
        return response;
      },
      (error: AxiosError) => {
        // Check if the error status is 401 (Unauthorized)
        if (error.response?.status && error.response.status === 401) {
          // remove all stored tokens
          removeAuthTokens();
          // reset persisted redux states, this will trigger routes logic in App.tsx
          persistor.purge();
        }
        // Return the error
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );
    
    export default instance;
```

6. `index.tsx`: This module dynamically defines routes based on the user's authentication status. It renders private or public layouts and routes accordingly.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    import { PrivateLayout, PublicLayout } from '@components/index';
    import { protectedRoutes } from './protectedRoutes';
    import { publicRoutes } from './publicRoutes';
    
    /**
     * Creates a router configuration based on authentication state.
     *
     * This function dynamically defines routes based on whether the user is authenticated or not.
     * It returns a `createBrowserRouter` configuration object for use with React Router DOM.
     *
     * @param isAuthenticated - A boolean indicating whether the user is currently authenticated.
     * @returns A `createBrowserRouter` configuration object.
     */
    const createRoutes = (isAuthenticated: boolean) =>
      createBrowserRouter([
        {
          element: isAuthenticated ? <PrivateLayout /> : <PublicLayout />,
          children: isAuthenticated ? protectedRoutes : publicRoutes,
        },
      ]);
    
    export default createRoutes;

`protectedRoutes.tsx`

    import React from 'react';
    import Profile from '@pages/User/Profile';
    import Dashboard from '@pages/Dashboard';
    import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export const protectedRoutes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        element: <Profile />,
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        element: <Navigate to="/" />,
      },
    ];
```

`publicRoutes.tsx`

```
    import React from 'react';
    import About from '@pages/About';
    import SignIn from '@pages/Auth/SignIn';
    import SignUp from '@pages/User/SignUp';
    import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export const publicRoutes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Navigate to="/sign-in" />,
      },
      {
        path: '/sign-in',
        element: <SignIn />,
      },
      {
        path: '/sign-up',
        element: <SignUp />,
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        element: <About />,
      },
      {
        path: '*',
        element: <Navigate to="/sign-in" />,
      },
    ];
```

---

**Specific Questions**:

1. **Correctness**: Does the implementation of the authentication system appear to be correct, especially in terms of handling unauthorized requests and clearing tokens?
2. **Error Handling**: Are there any potential error scenarios or edge cases that I may have overlooked in my implementation?
3. **Improvements**: Are there any improvements or optimizations that could be made to enhance the security, performance, or maintainability of the authentication system?
4. **Alternative Approaches**: Would you recommend any alternative approaches or best practices for managing authentication in a React application?

---

**Additional Information**:

I've included the folder tree structure and key code snippets for reference. Please let me know if any further details are needed.

```
src
│   App.tsx
│   index.tsx
│   react-app-env.d.ts
│
├───api
│       apiEndPoints.ts
│       index.ts
│
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   │       index.css
│   │
│   └───scss
│       │   main.scss
│       │
│       └───components
│               form.scss
│
├───components
│   │   index.ts
│   │
│   ├───Header
│   │       index.tsx
│   │
│   └───Layout
│           PrivateLayout.tsx
│           PublicLayout.tsx
│
├───configs
│       index.ts
│
├───hooks
│       useAuth.ts
│
├───pages
│   ├───About
│   │       index.tsx
│   │
│   ├───Auth
│   │   └───SignIn
│   │           index.tsx
│   │
│   ├───Dashboard
│   │       index.tsx
│   │
│   └───User
│       ├───Profile
│       │       index.tsx
│       │
│       └───SignUp
│               index.tsx
│
├───redux
│   │   store.ts
│   │
│   └───slices
│           auth.slice.ts
│
├───routes
│       index.tsx
│       protectedRoutes.tsx
│       publicRoutes.tsx
│
├───services
│       auth.service.ts
│       user.service.ts
│
├───types
│       auth.interface.ts
│       error.interface.ts
│       user.interface.ts
│
└───utils
        auth.ts
        common.ts
        errorHandler.ts
        storage.ts
```

The repository can be found [here](https://github.com/avishkakavindu/mern-fullstack-client)